# How do flash messages work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How does the framework associate `flash` messages with users?
How does it know when to apply it, i.e. after redirect?

Imagine a situation when in between adding a `flash` and loading the page the user was redirected to there comes some totally unconnected Ajax request. Will the Rails apply flash notices to the Ajax request?

Comment: Have a look at the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think flash hashes are associated with users.  They are stored in the sessions cookie on the user's browser in order to persist for the next request.  For the request following that one the flash hash clears itself out.

Comment: They are not stored in the session cookie. They are merely *associated* with the session cookie. The actual messages are stored in a Base64-encoded marshalled hash table in the `sessions` database table. This hash table also stores the CSRF token and possibly other site-specific things.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million What I described in my response is the default behavior for sessions since Rails 3: which uses “Cookie storage” or “super cookies” for sessions.  What you are describing is a session storage implemention via files or databases (ex: using the activerecord-session_store gem).  [this video on lynda.com](https://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Sessions/500551/540475-4.html?srchtrk=index%3a2%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3arails+%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2) is a great reference.  Unfortuantely you need to be a member to watch the video.